# could not deduce template argument

Tags: c++, dictionary, comparison, key

Part of the class I am implementing looks like this:

```
    struct Cord
    {
        int x_cord;
        int y_cord;
        Cord(int x = 0,int y = 0):x_cord(x),y_cord(y) {}
        bool operator()(const Cord& cord) const
        {
            if (x_cord == cord.x_cord)
            {
                return y_cord < cord.y_cord;
            }
            return x_cord < cord.x_cord;
        }
    };
class Cell
    {

    };
std::map<Cord,Cell> m_layout;
```

I can`t compile the code above getting

```
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'const Layout::Cord'
```

Any advices?

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with the code. The code above compiles fine. Look out for some code using `std::string`. Also look at the line number, the compiler provides.

Comment: @OlafDietsche it would only compile because the map has no elements. As soon as you try to add one, it would fail for the simple reason that `Cord` has no `operator<`.

Comment: @juanchopanza You're right, but that doesn't make the error message fit the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `operator()` should be `operator<`:

```
    bool operator<(const Cord& cord) const
    {
        if (x_cord == cord.x_cord)
        {
            return y_cord < cord.y_cord;
        }
        return x_cord < cord.x_cord;
    }
```

`operator<` is what `std::map` uses to order its keys.

Comment: apparently OP also has a comparison between a `std::string` and a `Cord` somewhere, from the looks of the error message

Answer (score 2):

You could fix this by providing an `operator<(const Cord&, const Cord&)`:

```
// uses your operator()
bool operator<(const Cord& lhs, const Cord& rhs) { return lhs(rhs);)
```

or re-naming `operator()(const Cord& cord) const` to `operator<(const Cord& cord) const`

Answer (score 2):

You are using your class in a `map` and it needs to define `operator<` for it.

```
// ...
bool operator<(const Cord& cord) const
{
  if (x_cord == cord.x_cord)
    return y_cord < cord.y_cord;
  return x_cord < cord.x_cord;
}
// ...
```